# Working with google places api

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I'm working with google places api and I would like to store the place suggestions as they are returned in a ko.observable array so that I can in tern use typeahead with the suggested places. Any idea on how to return the place suggestions back to the js?

Comment: so you like to re-invent the [**wheel**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete)?

Comment: well, essentially...yes. google autocomplete fails in a few key places. One being that if you tab out of the box it does not automatically select the first entry for you. I'm trying to overcome this through using typeahead which allows completes input with the first suggested option when you tab rather than leaving an incomplete string.